# How to typecast class of same name with same properties of one assembly to another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two classes with same name and same properties in different class libraries dlls.

This is the class in both libraries:

```
public class Employee {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> Charges { get; set; }
}
```

Dll 1 method where I am calling Dll 2 method:

```
public static async Task<Employee> PantryListItemCustomMapping(Employee employee, string employeeId)

{

var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == "MyAssemblyName (DLL 2)");

if(assembly != null)
{
                Type classType = CommonProps.CustomMappingAssembly.GetType(String.Format("NamespaceName.EmployeeHelper"));

                if (classType != null)
                {
                    // Create class instance.
                    var classInst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);

                    // Invoke required method.
                    MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("GetEmployeeMetaInfo");
                    if (methodInfo != null)
                    {
                        var task = (Task<Employee>)methodInfo.Invoke(classInst, new object[] { employee, employeeId });
                        var result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);

                        return (Employee)result;
                    }
                }

}

return null;


}
```

This is the method in second assembly dll:

```
public class EmployeeHelper
    {
        public async Task<Employee> GetEmployeeMetaInfo(Employee employee, string employeeId)
        {
            return employee;
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error saying Cannot convert: Employee into Employee

Comment: Indeed - those are *entirely* separate types as far as the CLR is concerned. The fact that they have the same namespace-qualified name is entirely coincidental to it. If at all possible, you should change your design to only have the class in one library.